# Picard group of a DM-stack

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, stacks

I wonder if the followings are true. Let $k$ be a field, $G/k$ is a finite constant group scheme acting on an affine $k$-scheme $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$. Then a line bundle on the quotient DM stack $[\mathrm{Spec}(A)/G]$ is equivalent to a locally free rank 1 $A$-module $M$, and a semi-linear action of $G$ on the A-module $M$. Thus we have a short exact sequence
\begin{align}
0\to H^1(G,A^{\times})\to Pic([\mathrm{Spec}(A)/G])\to Pic(\mathrm{Spec}(A))\to 0
\end{align}
where the 1st group cohomology $H^1(G,A^{\times})$ can be identified with the group of semi-linear characters $G\to A^{\times}$, so the pullback map $Pic([\mathrm{Spec}(A)/G])\to Pic(\mathrm{Spec}(A))$ has finite kernel.

More generally, if we have a DM quotient stack $[U/G]$, with non-affine but quasi-compact $U$, then we have a similar SES, where we only need to add some finite glueing data to the first term, so again the pullback map $Pic([U/G])\to Pic(U)$ has finite kernel.

Then I wonder for a separated quasi-compact DM-stack $\mathcal{X}$, if it is true that once we have an etale presentation $X\to \mathcal{X}$, the pullback map $Pic(\mathcal{X})\to Pic(X)$ has finite kernel.

Comment: The sequence that you write down is almost never right exact.  First of all, you should map into $\text{Pic}(\text{Spec}(A))^G$, the Abelian group of $G$-invariants.  Even that map is often not surjective, and the cokernel is a subgroup of $H^2(G,A^\times)$.

Comment: One source (certainly not the original source) is Remark 7.2 in "Lectures on invariant theory" by Igor Dolgachev.

Comment: The group $H^1(G,A^\times)$ can be infinite if $G$ is "wild", i.e., if the characteristic $p$ of $k$ divides the order of $G$.  For instance, if $A$ equals $k$ is a field of characteristic $p$, then $H^1(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z},A^\times)$ contains all the Artin-Schreier extensions, and these are indexed by the Abelian group $k/k^p$.  This group is often infinite.

Comment: . . . Actually, the Artin-Schreier extensions are indexed by $k/\psi(k)$ where $\psi:k\to k$ is the homomorphism of Abelian groups $\psi(x) = x^p-x$.  The quotient $k/\psi(k)$ can still be infinite.

Comment: Is your last paragraph supposed to be a general presentation, no longer a finite map? If you allow a Zariski cover, then the map on Picard groups can have infinite kernel, such as an affine cover of a complete curve.

Comment: @BenWieland   By a Zariski cover, you mean simply an open immersion? For an open immersion $X\to \mathcal{X}$, the kernel can of course be infinite. But for an etale presentation, I think I mean an etale, surjective morphism locally of finite presentation. Thanks for your example, though.

Comment: A disjoint union of the open subsets of an open cover, with the natural morphism that restricts to inclusion on each open, is an etale, surjective morphism that is locally of finite presentation.  If the schemes are Noetherian and the open cover is finite, the morphism is even quasi-compact.  Thus the comment by user @BenWieland is quite apropos.